# Import grid into Diva

Tags: import, grids-graticules, diva-gis

I am new DIVA - GIS user. I want to import country .grd file from diva - gis website. I tried with Bolivia, and it works fine, but it doesn't work with Bosnia (which actually is my subject of analysis), although the files are there.

Does anybody know what could be the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Hard to tell, but if you have imported Bosnia data following Bolivia, your map view would be kept at around Bolivia. Can you check if `Map | Zoom to Active Layer` change the look of it?